# Как правильно и есть ли смысловые различия: "пошла на обгон"," ушла на обгон", "зашла на обгон"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как правильно писать (говорить) и есть ли смысловые различия в выражениях:

"пошла на обгон", "ушла на обгон", "зашла на обгон"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычная (нейтральная)  фраза: **пошел на обгон.**

При этом **предмет** имеется в виду или указывается: *пошел на обгон грузовика, уверенно пошёл на обгон.*  Также может быть указано **место**: *пошел на обгон на узкой улице.*

Варианты *зашел на обгон, ушел на обгон* можно, вероятно,  применить **к общей стратегии водителя, например:** впереди было несколько машин, но он всё-таки  ушел/зашел на обгон, перестроившись в другой ряд.

Answer (score 2):

Безупречным выглядит только "**пошла на обгон**",  в значении "*решилась на обгон*" (напр. в протоколе о нарушении правил) или "*начала обгонять*".

Вариант "*зашла...*" выглядит несколько *жаргонным*, но ему можно приписать конкретный смысл "изменила положение машины для удобства обгона".

Вариант "ушла..." воспринимается странно, уж больно похоже на "ушла на обед" - такое выражение обычно связывают с покиданием какого-либо места (в контексте должна быть ясность, *какого именно*).